# Remove single alphabetic letters strings

Tags: r

In a string data column how is it possible to check in every row if exist a letter of alphabet and remove it.

Example

```
I am a text r r o n n r and here
```

And have as output this

```
I am a text and here
```

Comment: I think your condition needs  to be more specific, single alphabetic letter  'a' or 'I' is not removed

Comment: @akrun whatever is single character like r or o with space before and after remove it

Comment: Nathalie, why does the first `I` remain? Your rule of *"a letter of alphabet"* is too vague.

Comment: Does  `gsub('\\s{2,}', ' ', gsub('\\b[ron]\\b', '',  txt))` this works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
gsub("\\s[A-Za-z](?= )", "", "I am a text r r o n n r and here", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "I am text and here"
```

Since you want to preserve the single `a`, you can use any of the following for more-specific patterns:

```r
### just three letters: r o n
gsub("\\s[orn](?= )", "", "I am a text r r o n n r and here", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "I am a text and here"

### any single-letter except "a" and "i"
gsub("\\s[B-HJ-Zb-hj-z](?= )", "", "I am a text r r o n n r and here", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "I am a text and here"
```

(The exception for `i` in the second example is not strictly needed here, but provided as an example.)

The use of a "[look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)" (`(?= )` is used because you stated the requirement for a space before and after; if you use a pattern of `"\\s[orn]\\s"`, then it will miss many of the single letters (due to recursive replacements). If you relax this a little, then you can use word-boundaries, as in

```r
gsub("\\s[B-HJ-Zb-hj-z]\\b", "", "I am a text r r o n n r and here")
```

(While using perl-style regexes can technically have a performance penalty, I suspect that that really only matters if you're doing a lot and need to improve performance as much as you can. Not strictly required, and early optimization is *"the root of all evil"* - [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth))

Note: In this last pattern, I'm also excepting a lower-case `i` in addition to the upper-case `I`; if you are confident that you will never see an otherwise-valid `i`, then you can adjust your pattern to use `[B-HJ-Zb-z]` instead. (Thanks to @jay.sf for highlighting this assumption.)

Comment: Why are you accounting for the small `"i"`?

Comment: I did not want to assume case-sensitivity, that's all. It's easy enough to instead use `[B-HJ-Zb-z]`, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is not very clear

```
gsub('\\b[ron] ', '',  txt)
#[1] "I am a text and here"
```

Or using a more general approach

```
gsub("(?<=\\b\\K[a-z]) [a-z] ", "", txt, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "I am a text and here"
```

Or more simpler

```
gsub('\\b[a-z] [a-z] ', '', txt)
#[1] "I am a text and here"
```

---

Or with `str_remove_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(txt, "\\b[ron] ")
#[1] "I am a text and here"
```

#### data

```
txt <- "I am a text r r o n n r and here"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with stringr package as follows;

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# Create dataframe with column
data <-
  data.frame(
    A = c("I am a text r r o n n r and here")
  )

# Replacing ron in column with nothing
data %>%
  mutate(A = str_replace_all(A, "\\b[ron] \\b", ""))

# A
# I am a text and here
```